# Difference between Linear Actuator vs. Linear Actuator Mini

Tags: technic, piece-information, mechanical

I'd like to know the difference in terms of usage between the standard [Linear Actuator](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61927c01#T=S&O=%7B%7D):

[image]

vs. the ["mini" version](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92693c01#T=S&O=%7B%7D):

[image]

Both of these parts provide the really fun mechanic of translating rotational energy into lateral motion (the essence of an [actuator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuator)) in a particularly powerful way (in the sense of a [worm screw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worm_drive)).

My question revolves around the fact that the "standard" actuator is a lot more expensive.  When new it comes sealed in its own plastic bag.  The "mini" ones are a lot cheaper.  Aside from general differences in geometry associated with the two parts, is there any *other* reason one would choose the "standard" actuator? Does it provide any mechanical virtues one would want to consider when designing a build?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest difference I can think of that would impact my choice would be that the standard linear actuator is much more sturdy.

The standard linear actuator has a metal pole and is very rigid.

The mini linear actuators are made all of plastic, wiggle quite a bit, and whatever mechanism is inside will skip fairly easily.

Answer (score 7):

The large linear actuator extends 5 studs (from 11 retracted to 16 fully extended)

The small one extends 3 studs (from 7 retracted to 10 fully extended)

That's a large functional difference.